# Unable to fetch sessionId for Magento API using SOAP webservice in Android

Tags: php, android, web-services, magento, soap

I am developing an Android mobile app for Magento website, I have created user and set role in admin panel of Magento, but I am unable to fetch the sessionId from it. I am using soap web service and my code is for connecting to the web service is:

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:Magento";
private static final String URL  = "http://localhost.../index.php/api/index/index/?wsdl";
private static final String MAGENTO_METHOD_NAME = "login";


try {

    SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    env.dotNet = false;
    env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
    env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, MAGENTO_METHOD_NAME);

    request.addProperty("username", "web_service_all");
    request.addProperty("apiKey", "WebServiceUser";
    env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    androidHttpTransport.call("", env);

    Object result = env.getResponse();

    value=String.valueOf(so);
    Log.d("sessionId", result.toString());

} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
```